# How do I call a method of a running child activity from a parent activity?

Tags: android, methods, parent

I am developing an android app which has 3 tabs, created in MainActivity.java. Every tab has its own activity. In those activities I have a method called "Refresh()" to update the listview in that tab.
When the user clicks on a button the method "refreshTab(View v)" is called.

```
// Tab refreshen
public void refreshTab (View v) {
    Activity MyActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();        
    MyActivity.Refresh();       
}
```

This is throwing "The Method Refresh() is undefined for the type Activity. However, "MyActivity" is filled with the tab activity.
How would I go about getting this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the activity to your type of activity. Right now you are trying to call the Android class activity, which does not have a "Refresh" function.

Answer (score 0):

Your button handler is a little over-complicated (even though it's only two lines)...

Just do something like:

```
// Tab refreshen
public void refreshTab (View v) {  
    Refresh();       
}
```

If the way you've defined your `OnClickListener` is directly inline (but still within your activity's class), you may need to add a little direction, where `MyClassType` is the name of your class that extends `Activity`:

```
// Tab refreshen
public void refreshTab (View v) {  
    MyClassType.this.Refresh();       
}
```